# why isn't `react-router-dom` receiving query parameters across components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a component which sets a query string like so:

```
getUrl = () => {
  const { location } = this.props; // this is received from `withRouter`.
  return {
    ...location,
    search: qs.stringify(modifier(qs.parse(search))),
  }
};
```

where I am using it like as follows:

```
<NavLink to={getUrl((query) => ({ ...query, sort: 'desc' }))}>
  Sort Descending
</NavLink>
```

This will work "on it's own" and set the appropriate query param. However, elsewhere in my application, I am setting a different entry in the query param, like so:

```
<NavLink to={getUrl((query) => ({ ...query, sortBy: 'name' })}>
  Sort By Name
</NavLink>
```

What I expect is that when I click one, and then the other, I will receive a "joined" query string, i.e.,

`?sortBy=name&sort=desc`

However, it seems that `search` is undefined in the component delegating `sortBy`. I can change `sort` and it will update correctly, but any time I change `sortBy`, it completely rewrites the query string.

Perhaps this strategy isn't even viable to begin with for one reason or another. What would be the appropriate way to add a query parameter to the existing query parameters (or re-write)?

Answer (score 0):

in order to do something similar i wrote a utility function to append a query arg to the current url, and read the current url from the match param from withRouter.  something like

`to={appendQueryArg('desc', match.url)}`

edit: also make sure that the other place you are using it also uses withRouter...